# PHP $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] returning "\"

Tags: php, relative-path, filepath

So I have the following function in my php file:

```
 function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])) {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80" ) {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]. dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]).'/HPP_Receipt.php';
 } else{
 $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]).'/HPP_Receipt.php';
  }

  return $pageURL;
 }
```

For the most part it seems to be working properly. For example in my WAMP www folder, if I have this /HPP_Receipt file inside another folder it looks like this:

```
http://localhost/HPPCurrent/HPP_Receipt.php
```

which is correct. However if I switch it back to just the www folder, it gives me this result:

```
http://localhost\/HPP_Receipt.php
```

How can I make it so it doesn't give me the "\"? I have been trying to figure out but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I like to add the reason I am trying to make it so no matter where this file is it should be relative path aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])
```

Is the culprit. Also the fact that you have sub dir `HPPCurrent` on one server and you don't have it on the other server.  On windows servers directory paths mostly use `\` instead of `/`

You can trim out the `\` by using

```
rtrim(dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'\\')   // Will remove \ if present
```

**Note:** Don't get confused by `\\`, it will still remove the single one, you see two in that expression because first one is to escape the second one.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you @Hanky 웃 Panky